# How to change external CSS on the fly

Tags: javascript, css

I was recently looking for way to change CSS on the fly and not being able to find something, I was able to make it happen with inline CSS as demonstrated here: https://sid-sun.github.io/Change-CSS

But I am unable to find anything to change external CSS nor am I able to figure it out myself. The website I'm working with has a very large CSS and commonizing reduces only a minor part because both the styles are very different. Please give me a pointer and help me with it.

Thanks.

Comment: What aspect of the CSS do you want to change? The whole stylesheet? That's answered in [Changing Style Sheet javascript](//stackoverflow.com/q/14292997). Certain rules? That's answered in [Is it possible to alter a CSS stylesheet using JavaScript? (NOT the style of an object, but the stylesheet itself)](//stackoverflow.com/q/6620393)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id to the css import and change the `href` on click with js

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>New UI Mockup</title>
  <link href="dark.css" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
  var themeName = "dark";
  function changeTheme(){
   if (themeName == "dark"){
    themeName = "light";
   }
   else{
    themeName = "dark";
   }
   document.getElementById("theme").href = themeName + ".css";
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="title">Change Theme Demo</div>
 <div class="button" id="changeButton" onclick="changeTheme()">Change Theme</div>
 </body>
</html>
```